# How to Find Previous and Next Value for Days in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server

I Want to Find Previous Day Price and Next day price for each companyCode
I use This Query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.CompanyCode,p.Date),
p.Price
FROM Table1 p
)
SELECT
prev.price PreviousValue,
CTE.price,
nex.price NextValue
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
GO
```

But it is very Slowly, I Want Faster Query for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Use this Query For after SqlServer2012 Versions

```
SELECT CompanyCode,[Date],
LAG(p.Price) OVER (ORDER BY p.CompanyCode,p.[Date]) PreviousValue,
p.Price,
LEAD(p.Price) OVER (ORDER BY p.CompanyCode,p.[Date]) NextValue
FROM Table1 p 
order by CompanyCode,[Date]
```